# Синхронизация workspace Eclipse при наличии удалённого FTP-сервера

Tags: linux, eclipse, ftp, синхронизация

Наверное, это общий случай синхронизации через FTP, потому что средствами самого Eclipse так ничего внятного и не получается. Поэтому пока остановился на такой схеме: запускаем Eclipse скриптом, который

1. Скачивает с FTP архив, прибивает папку `.metadata` и распаковывает её из архива
2. Запускает IDE
3. Архивирует `.metadata` и закачивает на FTP

Попытки воспользоваться утилитами типа `lftp` для синхронизации без упаковки => совсем печальное ожидание :( Через архив получается в разы быстрей, если не на порядок. Но всё равно не так быстро, как хотелось бы. Исходные данные:

```
$ ls -Rf .metadata | wc -l
3081
$ du -hs .metadata    
93M     .metadata
```

Есть идеи как ускорить процесс?

---

P.S. В голове бродит мысль делать примерно то же самое, но через гит-репозиторий (при старте pull, при выходе commit/push), но пока не обдумал как следует.

Comment: а зачем вы что-то синхронизируете по ftp? какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, сверхзадача - синхронизировать воркспейсы эклипса на разных машинах, которые не могут использовать расшареные ресурсы (mylyn? не получилось). FTP потому, что на сервере, через который планируется синхронизация, больше ничего поднимать не планируется. А вариант с гит пока не пробовал.

Comment: Зачем надо синхронизировать это?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, небольшая поправка: синхронизируется только рабочее окружение, сами проекты - через git, конечно же. Смысл в том, что сев за один компьютер, получить среду в точно таком же состоянии, в котором оставил её на другом. Включая такие мелочи, как заметки, например. В принципе можно вообще всё синхронизировать, но это уже излишество. Тем более что тащит за собой гигов 80 :)

Comment: а что включает в себя окружение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Берём [Resilio Sync](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resilio_Sync) (бывший BTSync).
2. Ставим.
3. Идём на http://localhost:8888/gui/.
4. Выбираем в настройках русский язык и шарим ту папку, которую надо синкать в режиме "Чтение и запись", снимаем галку "Ссылка действительна N дней", копируем ключ "Чтение и запись".
5. На тачке, **куда** надо синкать выполняем первые 3 пункта, а потом жмём на стрелку "Вниз" около "Добавить папку" -> "Введите ключ или ссылку". Вбиваем ключ, указываем **куда** синкать.
6. Радуемся жизни.

P.S. Есть ещё [Syncthing](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syncthing). Функционал похож, а ещё можно поднять внутри Docker свой трекер и вообще в интернеты трафик не выпускать.

Все проги идут и под линуксом и под виндой и под ведром тоже неплохо себя чувствуют.

Comment: Так, стоп. А в другую сторону это будет работать?

Comment: В обе. Кто первый поменял - от того синк и идёт другим участникам.

Comment: А можно только в одну. Мастер меняет - другим приходит. Другие меняют - изменения только у них и остаются.

Comment: Ага, спасибо. Поэкспериментирую :)

Comment: @PinkTux, неужели получилось?

Answer (score 0):

Через `git` оказалось проще. Использовал [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/), так как там дают бесплатно приватные репозитории. Допустим, создали приватный репозиторий `my-metadata`. Дальше:

```
$ cd $WORKSPACE/.metadata
$ git init
$ git remote add origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/$USER/my-metadata.git
$ git add -f --all
$ git push -u origin master
```

Ключ `-f` нужен для добавления всех файлов и каталогов, так как у меня, например, почти все они попадают под глобальные настройки `.gitignore`.

Eclipse запускается так:

```
#!/bin/bash

WORKSPACE="..."
ECLIPSE_BIN="..."
#
# Здесь можно распарсить этот файл для определения дефолтного 
# workspace при запуске без ключей:
# $ECLIPSE_DIR/configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs
#
# При необходимости обработать ключ -data (явное указание workspace)
#
cd "$WORKSPACE/.metadata"
git pull

"$ECLIPSE_BIN" "$@"

cd "$WORKSPACE/.metadata"
git commit -am "$(date)"
git push
```

Теперь на всех машинах будет одно и то же окружение со всеми изменениями, которые сделаны на одной из них.

**NB!** Само собой, должны быть синхронизироаны и сами копии Eclipse, со всеми плагинами и т.д. Но это уже не регулярная задача (хотя, при желании, можно вставить сюда же).

Comment: А если через какой-нить `resilio` или `syncthing`?

Comment: @donRumata, а они умеют синхронизировать именно каталоги, то есть делать то же, что и `rsync -a --delete`? Надо: 1) скачали мастер-копию каталога  2) работаем, в результате в нём удаляются/изменяются/добавляются файлы 3) завершили работу - обновили мастер-копию. Не уверен что это полезно - постоянно обновлять мастера в процессе работы.

Comment: Ну да. Синк при наличии сети идёт в реалтайме.

Comment: @donRumata, да и пусть идёт, если не затыкается на постоянно изменяемых файлах. Вопрос в другом: насколько адекватно оно будет синхронизировать именно содержимое каталога (с учётом удалённых файлов в том числе)? А одновременное обращение с двух машин не планируется by design.

Comment: В классической настройке (без режима бэкапа) с равноправными машинами (без ro) всё синкается 1в1. Удаляем там - удаляется тут. Добавляем тут - добвляется там.

Comment: @donRumata, а напишите как ответ, с какими-то минимальными подробностями. У варианта с гитом всё-таки есть недостатки, этот мне уже кажется даже лучше :)